# Parsing XML received in String to get lat and long

Tags: java, xml

I need to parse this xml which i am receiving in String format i want to extract lat and lon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
   <cell 
      lat="13.035037526666665" 
      lon="77.56784941333333" 
      mcc="404" 
      mnc="45" 
      lac="1020" 
      cellid="13443" 
      averageSignalStrength="0" 
      range="-1" 
      samples="15" 
      changeable="1" 
      radio="GSM" />
</rsp>
```

Please can anyone help me on this

I have tried this but not getting output

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource src = new InputSource();
src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(data));

Document doc = builder.parse(src);
String lat = doc.getElementsByTagName("lat").item(0).getTextContent();
String lon = doc.getElementsByTagName("lon").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a lot of XML parsers for Java (just search for DOM)

Comment: see the edits i have tried DocumentBuilder

Comment: If this is the only thing you need, you may opt to just use a regex and skip completely the XML parsing.

Comment: Parsing XML via RegEx is always a bad advice. How do you handle commented out elements? Multi line elements? Same elements in deeper structure? Validation? Encoding in prolog? Namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

`lat` is an attribute of the element `cell`. So you should not use `getElementsByTagName("lat")` but `getAttribute("lat")`: (code untested)

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource src = new InputSource();
src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(data));

Document doc = builder.parse(src);
Element docElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
String lat = docElement.getElementsByTagName("cell").item(0).getAttribute("lat");
String lon = docElement.getElementsByTagName("cell").item(0).getAttribute("lon");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("C:\\dev\\Workspace\\ahportal\\benefits-base-sdk\\portlets\\ah-hm-enrl-charts-portlet\\docroot\\WEB-INF\\src\\com\\aonhewitt\\portal\\base\\charts\\bean\\employee.xml"));
        NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node instanceof Element) {  
                System.out.println("lat=> " + node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("lat")
                        .getNodeValue());

                System.out.println("lon=> " + node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("lon")
                        .getNodeValue());
            }

        }
    }
```

Please try above code. It should work. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the coordinates, I would recommend to wrap them into an location object, holding lat & lon.
I would not recommend to use the DOM API, but a data binding lib like JAXB, or for a shorter and more flexible approach a [data projection library](http://xmlbeam.org) (DISCLOSURE: I'm affiliated with that project) and have the values automatically converted to `Double`.

```
import org.xmlbeam.XBProjector;
import org.xmlbeam.annotation.XBRead;

public class ReadCoords {

  // Object holding coordinates
  public interface Location {

    // Access methods for coordinates
    @XBRead("./@lat")
    Double getLat();

    @XBRead("./@lon")
    Double getLon();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Location location = new  XBProjector().io().url("res://data.xml").evalXPath("/rsp/cell").as(Location.class);
    System.out.println(location.getLat()+"/"+location.getLon());
  }
}
```